# Python script to add data to postgres docker container runs multiple times

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to find a good way to populate a database with initial data for a simple application.  I'm using a tutorial from realpython.com as a starting point.  I then run a simple python script after the database is created to add a single entry, but when I do this the data is added multiple times even though I only call the [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUDgx.png) once. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL4qt.png)

population script (test.py):

```
   from app import db                                                                                                                                                          
   from models import *                                                                                                                                                        

   t = Post("Hello 3")                                                                                                                                                         
   db.session.add(t)                                                                                                                                                           
   db.session.commit()
```

edit:

Here is the docker-compose file which i use to build the project:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 app:app

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

data:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

it references two different Dockerfiles:

Dockerfile #1 which builds the App container and is 1 line:

```
FROM python:3.4-onbuild
```

Dockerfile #2 is used to build the nginx container

```
FROM tutum/nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD sites-enabled/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

edit2:

Some people have suggested that the data was persisting over several runs, and that was my initial thought as well. This is not the case, as I remove all active docker containers via docker rm before testing.  Also the number of "extra" data is not consistent, ranging randomly from 3-6 in the few tests that I have run so far.

Comment: Full code project is here: [Repo](https://github.com/aleedom/Docker-Testing). I'm following this  [Tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/dockerizing-flask-with-compose-and-machine-from-localhost-to-the-cloud/).

Comment: Can you show your dockerfile, your docker run?

Comment: @user2915097 I updated the post with the docker-compose file as well as the 2 Dockerfiles it references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug related to using the run command on containers with the "restart: always" instruction in the docker-compose/Dockerfile.  In order to resolve this issue without a bug fix I removed the "restart: always" from the web container.

related issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1013